# Invalid Credential Provided error on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I try to link my django project to heroku and keep getting `Invalid credentials provided.`
I have use heroku before but now I just don't understand what is happening

I also get to see  `https://cli-auth.heroku.com/auth/cli/browser/8` which opens up in the web browser and shows `bad request`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by "link my django project to heroku"? Are you trying to deploy to Heroku? How? What _specifically_ are you doing that generates this message? Please read [ask].

Comment: i am trying to deploy to heroku....i typed heroku create and it brought out that error message `Invalid credentials provided.` and I need help on how to solve this

Comment: "i typed heroku create"—that should be in the _question_, not a comment. Please [edit] your question and add this. Have you authenticated by running `heroku login` [as documented in the getting started guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#getting-started)? We really need as much clarity as possible if we're going to be able to help you. Again, please read [ask].